# Android JavaMail can't send message

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I followed instruction [Link](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) for sending mail. I have added Internet uses-permission and method which send an email calls in `AsyncTask`. But I still can't to send an email. I always receive ad error in the row `Transport.send(message);`.

Here my printStack:`06-04 14:49:32.203: W/System.err(32750): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
06-04 14:49:32.203: W/System.err(32750):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:428)
06-04 14:49:32.203: W/System.err(32750):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239)
06-04 14:49:32.203: W/System.err(32750):    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:292)
06-04 14:49:32.203: W/System.err(32750):    at javax.mail.URLName.getHostAddress(URLName.java:487)
06-04 14:49:32.203: W/System.err(32750):    at javax.mail.URLName.hashCode(URLName.java:463)
06-04 14:49:32.203: W/System.err(32750):    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:263)
06-04 14:49:32.203: W/System.err(32750):    at javax.mail.Session.getPasswordAuthentication(Session.java:823)
06-04 14:49:32.203: W/System.err(32750):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:271)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at com.vakoms.infouser.utils.GmailSender.sendMail(GmailSender.java:66)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at com.vakoms.infouser.utils.SendMessageTask.send(SendMessageTask.java:31)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at com.vakoms.infouser.utils.SendMessageTask.doInBackground(SendMessageTask.java:16)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at com.vakoms.infouser.utils.SendMessageTask.doInBackground(SendMessageTask.java:1)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-04 14:49:32.213: W/System.err(32750):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-04 14:49:32.223: W/System.err(32750):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-04 14:49:32.223: W/System.err(32750):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-04 14:49:32.223: W/System.err(32750):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-04 14:49:32.223: W/System.err(32750):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-04 14:49:32.223: W/System.err(32750):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
06-04 14:49:32.223: W/System.err(32750): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
06-04 14:49:32.223: W/System.err(32750):    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
06-04 14:49:32.223: W/System.err(32750):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
06-04 14:49:32.223: W/System.err(32750):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:415)
06-04 14:49:32.233: W/System.err(32750):    ... 22 more
06-04 14:49:32.233: W/System.err(32750): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
06-04 14:49:32.233: W/System.err(32750):    ... 25 more`

Comment: permission denied means you don't have the internet uses-permission

Comment: But I have this permissions: `   <uses-permission android:name="android.permissoin.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your permission name. It should read:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and not `...android.permissoin...`